# Finding the sum of multiple inputted Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I am finding the sum of multiple arrays and have searched various codes and programs but it seems none has worked for me or should I say none has actually made my brain work to create a code based on what I saw. **"What I am trying to do is to add the 3 inputed Grade Arrays and then divide it by 3 to get the Array for Average."**

```
package Activity;

import java.util.*;

public class TestCode {
  static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  static int indexMax = 3;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String InfoName[][] = new String[indexMax][2];
    Double InfoGrade[][] = new Double[indexMax][3];

    InputInfoName(InfoName);
    InputGrade(InfoGrade);

    PrintInfo(InfoName, ComputeAvg);
  }

  public static String[][] InputInfoName(String NameArr[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indexMax; i++) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Enter Student[" + (i + 1) + "]'s Full Name");
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("First Name: ");
      NameArr[i][0] = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Last Name: ");
      NameArr[i][1] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    return NameArr;
  }

  public static Double[][] InputGrade(Double GradeArr[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indexMax; i++) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Enter Student[" + (i + 1) + "]'s Grades");
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("1st Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][2] = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("2nd Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][3] = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("3rd Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][4] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    return GradeArr;
  }
  // Main Problem
  public static Double[][] ComputeAvg(Double ComputeArr[][]) {
    Double AddAvg[][] = new Double[indexMax][];
    Double getAvg[][] = new Double[indexMax][];

    for (int i = 0; i < indexMax; i++) {
      AddAvg[i][] = // I don't know what is next
    }
    return ComputeArr;
  }
  // End of Main Problem
  public static void PrintInfo(String arr[][], Double ComputeAvg[]) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Student Info");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      System.out.println("Student[" + i + "]: " + arr[i][0] + "," + arr[i][1] + "     Average: " + ComputeAvg[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Side-note** Personally, I would replace the use of the `Double` object by the primitive-type `double`, mainly because of (apart from performance) readability and because in your code is not really needed.

Create the array that will keep the average by array:

```
Double AddAvg[] = new Double[indexMax];
```

iterate through the arrays and get the average of those arrays using Java streams:

```
  Arrays.stream(ComputeArr[i])
        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
        .average()
        .orElse(0);
```

The full method:

```
   public static Double[] ComputeAvg(Double[][] ComputeArr) {
        Double[] AddAvg = new Double[indexMax];

        for (int i = 0; i < indexMax; i++) {
            AddAvg[i] =  Arrays.stream(ComputeArr[i])
                                .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                .average()
                                .orElse(0);
        }
        return AddAvg;
    }
```

If you cannot use streams then do the sum *manually*:

```
public static Double[] ComputeAvg(Double[][] ComputeArr) {
    Double[] AddAvg = new Double[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int j = 0; j < ComputeArr[i].length; j++) {
            sum += ComputeArr[i][j];
        }
        AddAvg[i] = sum /  ComputeArr[i].length;
    }
    return AddAvg;
}
```

In Java arrays indexed from 0 to the size of the array -1. So this method:

```
  public static Double[][] InputGrade(Double GradeArr[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indexMax; i++) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Enter Student[" + (i + 1) + "]'s Grades");
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("1st Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][2] = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("2nd Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][3] = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("3rd Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][4] = sc.nextDouble();

    }
    return GradeArr;
  }
```

is accessing positions outside the boundaries of the array `GradeArr` (i.e., `GradeArr[i][4]`). Change to :

```
  public static Double[][] InputGrade(Double GradeArr[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indexMax; i++) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Enter Student[" + (i + 1) + "]'s Grades");
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("1st Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][0] = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("2nd Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][1] = sc.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("3rd Grade: ");
      GradeArr[i][2] = sc.nextDouble();

    }
    return GradeArr;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use Stream API, the averages of 2D Double array may be calculated using [`DoubleStream::average`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average--):

```java
static Double[] calcAvg(Double[][] arr) {
    return Arrays
        .stream(arr) // Stream<Double[]>
        .map(inner -> Arrays.stream(inner)   // Stream<Double>
                .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue) // convert to primitive double
                .average()    // average calculated as OptionalDouble
                .orElse(0.0)  // in case of empty array
        )
        .toArray(Double[]::new);
}
```

Also, [`Collectors::averagingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) may be used to make it even less verbose:

```java
static Double[] calcAvg(Double[][] arr) {
    return Arrays
        .stream(arr) // Stream<Double[]>
        .map(inner -> Arrays.stream(inner)
                .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue)) // or x -> x
        )
        .toArray(Double[]::new);
}
```

Tests

```java
Double[][] arr = {
  {},
  {0.1},
  {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
  {4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0},
  {5.0, 11.0, 17.0, 23.0, 29.0, 35.0},
};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(calcAvg(new Double[0][])));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(calcAvg(arr)));
```

Output:

```
[]
[0.0, 0.1, 2.0, 6.0, 20.0]
```